# Android Shared Element Transition supportFinishAfterTransition() transits to wrong item

Tags: android

I would be so happy if anyone could help me. (I'm new to programming btw)

**Overview**

I have a RecyclerView with many items in it. On my MainActivity, I show the RecyclerView. When I click an item, the app moves to the DetailActivity to show more details about the particular item.

I want to use Shared Element Transition when I move from one Activity to another. 
When I click on Item 1, Item 1 is the Shared Element in transition. When supportFinishAfterTransition is called, I want Item 1 to stay as the Shared Element in the transition from DetailActivity back to MainActivity.

I was able to achieve my goals initially, until I setReverseLayout and setStackFromEnd to be true. Now, the forward transition is right, but on backward transition, the Item the Shared Element Transition is swapped.

ie. Say I have three items, 1, 2, 3. On forward, 1 goes to 1. On backward, 1 goes to 3.

For 3, on forward, 3 goes to 3. On backward, 3 goes to 1.

I need help fixing this.

**The Code**

the code for setting RecyclerView

```
//setting up RecyclerView
    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    llm.setReverseLayout(true);
    llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    if (DataForAlarms.myAlarmsList.size() != 0) {
        final RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(DataForAlarms.myAlarmsList);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //sets up Item clicking
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), rv, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                Alarms alarm = DataForAlarms.myAlarmsList.get(position);
                if(alarm.isAcknowledged()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(DetailActivity.ID, alarm.getID());

                    String myTransitionName = "";
                    //Transition code from main to detail activity
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){

                        myTransitionName = getString(R.string.transition_alarm_card) + String.valueOf(position);
                        view.findViewById(R.id.alertImage).setTransitionName(myTransitionName);
                        i.putExtra(UNIQUE_TRANSITION_NAME,myTransitionName);
                        Log.e("Transition",myTransitionName);
                    }

                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(

                            MainActivity.this,

                            // For each shared element, add to this method a new Pair item,
                            // which contains the reference of the view we are transitioning *from*,
                            // and the value of the transitionName attribute
                            new Pair<>(view.findViewById(R.id.alertImage),
                                    myTransitionName)

                    );

                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    ActivityCompat.startActivity(MainActivity.this, i, options.toBundle());
                } else{
                    view.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
```

the code for setting transition name on detailActivity

```
//set transition name
    String myTransitionName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.UNIQUE_TRANSITION_NAME);
    Log.e("Transition",myTransitionName);

    //to exclude status bar and navigation bar from transition
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>20){
        alertImage.setTransitionName(myTransitionName);
        Transition fade = new Fade();
        fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
        fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    }
```

and finally, the code for going back

```
//allow clicking on cv to go back to MainActivity
    cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(DetailActivity.ID, alarm.getID());
            supportFinishAfterTransition();
        }
    });
```

**How it was intend**
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky7cQ.gif

In the above gif (credits to codepath), item 2 is the shared element in both the transition forward and backwards. What is happening to me is, 1 is in forward, but 3 is in backwards. But when 3 is in forward, 1 is in backwards.

Thanks in advance